# PAM SSH authentication pam_exec

Tags: linux, ssh, security, authentication, pam

I am trying to bypass SSH password authentication if some shell script return success code (0).

this is my configuration. Please help to fix this if possible or suggest me if need change solution

```
auth    sufficient pam_exec.so expose_authtok /root/ppaamm.sh
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so
```

script content

```
cat /root/ppaamm.sh
exit 0
```